# Cannot install any libraries

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip

I just installed pycharm to my new MacBook Air M1. I am trying to set up pycharm and I found out that I cannot install any libraries. (I tried package installer, package manager, and macOS terminal) Through macOS I get this error:

Any ideas how to solve this? (btw: I have the exact same problem with my PC)

```
§pip install jupiter 
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement jupiter (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for jupiter
```

pip debugger information:

```
§pip debug
WARNING: This command is only meant for debugging. Do not use this with automation for parsing and getting these details, since the output and options of this command may change without notice.
pip version: pip 21.1.2 from /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pip (python 3.9)
sys.version: 3.9.1 (v3.9.1:1e5d33e9b9, Dec  7 2020, 12:44:01) 
[Clang 12.0.0 (clang-1200.0.32.27)]
sys.executable: /usr/local/bin/python3.9
sys.getdefaultencoding: utf-8
sys.getfilesystemencoding: utf-8
locale.getpreferredencoding: UTF-8
sys.platform: darwin
sys.implementation:
  name: cpython
'cert' config value: Not specified
REQUESTS_CA_BUNDLE: None
CURL_CA_BUNDLE: None
pip._vendor.certifi.where(): /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pip/_vendor/certifi/cacert.pem
pip._vendor.DEBUNDLED: False
vendored library versions:
  appdirs==1.4.4
  CacheControl==0.12.6
  colorama==0.4.4
  distlib==0.3.1
  distro==1.5.0 (Unable to locate actual module version, using vendor.txt specified version)
  html5lib==1.1
  msgpack==1.0.2 (Unable to locate actual module version, using vendor.txt specified version)
  packaging==20.9
  pep517==0.10.0
  progress==1.5
  pyparsing==2.4.7
  requests==2.25.1
  certifi==2020.12.05
  chardet==4.0.0
  idna==3.1
  urllib3==1.26.4
  resolvelib==0.7.0
  setuptools==44.0.0 (Unable to locate actual module version, using vendor.txt specified version)
  six==1.15.0
  tenacity==7.0.0 (Unable to locate actual module version, using vendor.txt specified version)
  toml==0.10.2
  webencodings==0.5.1 (Unable to locate actual module version, using vendor.txt specified version)
Compatible tags: 327
  cp39-cp39-macosx_11_0_arm64
  cp39-cp39-macosx_11_0_universal2
  cp39-cp39-macosx_10_16_universal2
  cp39-cp39-macosx_10_15_universal2
  cp39-cp39-macosx_10_14_universal2
  cp39-cp39-macosx_10_13_universal2
  cp39-cp39-macosx_10_12_universal2
  cp39-cp39-macosx_10_11_universal2
  cp39-cp39-macosx_10_10_universal2
  cp39-cp39-macosx_10_9_universal2
  ...
  [First 10 tags shown. Pass --verbose to show all.]
```

Comment: What other libraries that **do exist** are you having issues with?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By the looks of the error, it cannot detect any library named `jupiter`, probably because it doesn't exist.

If you are trying to install the `Jupyter` library, instead try installing it like this:

`pip3 install jupyterlab`

[Jupyter's installation page](https://jupyter.org/install)

Answer (score 2):

If you are referring to Jupyter Lab, you will need to install it using this command line:

```
pip install jupyterlab
```

Whereas with PyCharm, you will need to get the `.dmg` from the official JetBrains [website](https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/download/#section=mac).

As for your Windows OS, you can download something like Anaconda and use this in the command line:

```
conda install -c conda-forge jupyterlab
```

[Here](https://mycarta.wordpress.com/2019/07/09/from-zero-to-jupyterlab-pro-on-windows-10/) is the website for more info on Windows installation.

I hope that helped.